# How do I manually add brackets to a boxplot with a categorical x axis varibale?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a dataset with counts of two different fish species at different depths and made a graph with the following code:

```
depth<-c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10)
count<-c(10,6,13,2,16,4,9,1,17,3,20,4,11,5,13,14,12,10,15,7,14,8,16,5,12,9,15,10)
species<- c('a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b')
df<-data.frame(depth, count, species)
df

df$depth<- factor(df$depth, levels = c("5", "10"))

#making the plot
ggplot(data=df, aes(depth, count, fill=species))+geom_boxplot()+
   labs(x="Depth", y="Number", fill= "Species")
```

[easy plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm0nT.png)

I now want to manually add brackets that indicate the significant differences between the two fish species per depth. I managed to add brackets but I can only make them go from depth=5 to depth=10 and i cannot find a way to point from one species at depth=5 to the other. This is how I add brackets between the two depths (what I don't want to do):

```
   labs(x="Depth", y="Number", fill= "Species")+geom_bracket(
    xmin = c("5","5"), xmax = c("10","10"),
    y.position = c(40,30) ,label.size = 5, label = c("***", "*"),inherit.aes = FALSE,
    tip.length = c(0.01, 0.01))
```

Which numbers do I have to use for xmin and xmax to draw a bracket between the two species at the same depth?

Thank you in advance,
Anni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ggplot_build` to check the `x` positions of your boxplot and use them as xmin and xmax like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
#making the plot
p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(depth, count, fill=species))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(x="Depth", y="Number", fill= "Species") 

q <- ggplot_build(p)
q$data[[1]]$x[1:2]
#> [1] 0.8125 1.1875
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "mapped_discrete" "numeric"
q$data[[1]]$x[3:4]
#> [1] 1.8125 2.1875
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "mapped_discrete" "numeric"

p + geom_bracket(
    xmin = c(q$data[[1]]$x[1:2]), xmax = c(q$data[[1]]$x[3:4]),
    y.position = c(40,30) ,label.size = 5, label = c("***", "*"),inherit.aes = FALSE,
    tip.length = c(0.01, 0.01))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>